# Reporting Services: find all items deployed in a specific timeframe

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

If you put the reportmanager in listview you can see who deployed which report and when.
Can I retrieve this information somewhere and store it in a table for analysis?

I cannot seem to find how to do this, I did look through views and the internet but nothing to be found...

Any clues? Or is this not possible?

Grtz H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the ReportServer database tables to get this information.

Try something like:

```
select reportPath = r.Path
  , report = r.Name
  , created = r.CreationDate
  , createdBy = c.UserName
  , modified = r.ModifiedDate
  , modifiedBy = m.UserName
from Catalog r -- report
  inner join Users c on r.CreatedByID = c.UserID -- created
  inner join Users m on r.ModifiedByID = m.UserID -- modified
where r.Type = 2 -- report catalog items only
```

Which returns information on all reports on the server, with created time/user and modified time/user.

You can filter by the datetime values as required.